# como sumar valores de de DATATABLE Con filtros

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Tengo una tabla creada con `datatable` que tiene unos filtros, lo que quisiera es sumar unos valores de la tabla mientras se filtren me sume 4 columnas sólo los totales y me los muestre en un `input`, que sean dinámicos mientras se vaya filtrando la tabla me muestre los totales.

**JS**

```js
$('.tablareporte606').DataTable({
  "deferRender": true,
  "retrieve": true,
  "processing": true,
  initComplete:function(){
    this.api().columns().every(function(){
      var column = this;
      var select = $('<select class="form-control"><option value=""></option></select>').appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() ).on( 'change', function () {
        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val());
        column.search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false ).draw();
      });
      column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
        select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>')
      });
    });
  },
  "language": {
    "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
    "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
    "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
    "sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
    "sInfo": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
    "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
    "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
    "sInfoPostFix": "",
    "sSearch": "Buscar:",
    "sUrl": "",
    "sInfoThousands": ",",
    "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
    "oPaginate": {
      "sFirst": "Primero",
      "sLast": "Último",
      "sNext": "Siguiente",
      "sPrevious": "Anterior"
    },
    "oAria": {
      "sSortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
      "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
    }
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped dt-responsive tablareporte606"  width="100%">
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.tablareporte606').DataTable({
    "deferRender": true,
    "retrieve": true,
    "processing": true,
    "paging": true,
    "autoWidth": true,
    initComplete:function(){
        this.api().columns().every(function(){
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select class="form-control"><option value=""></option></select>').appendTo( $(column.header()).empty() ).on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val());

                    column.search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false ).draw();} );

            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>')
            });
        });

},
"footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
            var api = this.api();
            nb_cols = api.columns().nodes().length;
            var j = 6;
            while(j < nb_cols){
                var pageTotal = api.column( j, { page: 'current'} ).data().reduce( function (a, b) {
                return Number(a) + Number(b);
            }, 0 );
      // Update footer
      $( api.column( j ).footer() ).html(pageTotal);
                j++;
            } 
        },



"language": {
    "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
    "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
    "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
    "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
    "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
    "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
    "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
    "sInfoPostFix":    "",
    "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
    "sUrl":            "",
    "sInfoThousands":  ",",
    "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
    "oPaginate": {
        "sFirst":    "Primero",
        "sLast":     "Último",
        "sNext":     "Siguiente",
        "sPrevious": "Anterior"
    },
    "oAria": {
        "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
        "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
    }
}
```

});

```
así lo he logrado
```

Comment: Por favor lee cómo responder y explica paso a paso tu solución para que tengas una respuesta aceptada y ayudes a otros usuarios a entender mejor la respuesta.

Comment: Revisar [answer]